# can we do field dependencies by using apex

Tags: apex

My requirement is when i select patient Status active, my dependent field is checkbox. when i select patient status as under treatment need to display a date field and a picklist as dependent fields. please provide some solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this sample code for reference (taken from 
http://www.infallibletechie.com/2012/10/dependent-picklist-using-apex-in.html)

Visualforce page:

```
<apex:page controller="sample">

    <apex:form >

    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">
            <apex:pageblockSectionItem>
                <apex:outputLabel value="State"/>
            </apex:pageblockSectionItem>        
            <apex:pageblockSectionItem>                
                <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!state}">
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!states}"/>
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="a"/>
                </apex:selectList>                
            </apex:pageblockSectionItem>
            <apex:pageblockSectionItem>
                <apex:outputLabel value="City"/>
            </apex:pageblockSectionItem>            
            <apex:pageblockSectionItem>
                <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!city}" id="a">
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!cities}"/>
                </apex:selectList>
            </apex:pageblockSectionItem>            
        </apex:pageBlockSection>        
    </apex:pageBlock>

    </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

Apex Code:

```
public class sample
{
    public String state {get;set;}
    public String city {get;set;}

    public List<SelectOption> getStates()
    {
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        options.add(new SelectOption('None','--- None ---'));        
        options.add(new SelectOption('TN','Tamil Nadu'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('KL','Kerala'));
        return options;
    } 

    public List<SelectOption> getCities()
    {
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        if(state == 'TN')
        {       
            options.add(new SelectOption('CHE','Chennai'));
            options.add(new SelectOption('CBE','Coimbatore'));
        }
        else if(state == 'KL')
        {       
            options.add(new SelectOption('COA','Coachin'));
            options.add(new SelectOption('MVL','Mavelikara'));
        }
        else
        {
            options.add(new SelectOption('None','--- None ---'));
        }      
        return options;
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

approach it as traditional dynamic HTML, but feel free to use VF tags.  You need to use javascript to decide which parts of your UI/markup to reveal, based on client-side actions.  This is different from a dependant picklist because you are changing the controls, not just the elements of a picklist.